# Java: How to persist Weka Naive Bayes Classifier?

Tags: java, persistence, classification, weka

Is there any way to persist after training Weka Naive Bayes Classifier to a file?
I have data-set with 50 million of records and training classifier takes many hours. I would like to save trained classifier to a file and use it later with different test sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After training, you can right click on the result that appears in Result List in left bottom and click Save Model. You can load that model later to apply it on a different test set.

Comment: I use Weka classifier class in my Java program. How to save model from Java?

Comment: There is an example [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization) on how to save model with java API.